# 404 Page Not Found errors on existing pages

Tags: php, model-view-controller, http-headers

I have build a PHP MVC framework, pretty much like ZF1.x, for learning purposes and private use, anyways I started putting it at a test with link cloaking script, but every time I visit a page I see the expected content and in chrome developer tools, under network tab I see 404 for the page itself, but everything is working perfectly.

**Side Note:** When the page doesn't exist I see the MVc doing its job to route the request to the ErrorController and all is well (I get response code '200 OK')

Problem in short: I receive **404 Page Not Found** on existing pages, but non-existent ones I see the expected 404, 500, or 503 pages with **HTTP 200 OK**, any ideas from where to begin searching/fixing it?

***My .htaccess***

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

***VHost:***

```
NameVirtualHost mvc.local:80

<VirtualHost mvc.local:80>
    ServerName mvc.local
    DocumentRoot C:\Server\Apache2.2\htdocs\www\public
</VirtualHost>
```

***Rewirte Log @ Lvl 4***

```
    127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x -> x
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'x'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x' pattern='-s' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x' pattern='-l' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x' pattern='-d' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x -> x
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'x'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'x' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c1a8/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1193020/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add path info postfix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png -> img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'img/banner.png'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img' pattern='-s' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img' pattern='-l' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img' pattern='-d' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add path info postfix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png -> img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'img/banner.png'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'img/banner.png' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a1a0/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:49 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118c560/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-s' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-l' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-d' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'favicon.ico' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195068/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:50 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#118a250/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x -> x
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'x'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x' pattern='-s' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x' pattern='-l' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x' pattern='-d' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/x -> x
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'x'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'x' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191058/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1195028/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add path info postfix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png -> img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'img/banner.png'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img' pattern='-s' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img' pattern='-l' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img' pattern='-d' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add path info postfix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/img/banner.png -> img/banner.png
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'img/banner.png'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'img/banner.png' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b080/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1191410/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-s' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-l' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico' pattern='-d' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/favicon.ico -> favicon.ico
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'favicon.ico'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'favicon.ico' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip document_root prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> /index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#1188198/initial] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (4) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] RewriteCond: input='C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php' pattern='-s' => matched
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] strip per-dir prefix: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] applying pattern '^.*$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (2) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] rewrite 'index.php' -> 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2013:13:06:53 +0100] [mvc.local/sid#435378][rid#119b130/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/] initial URL equal rewritten URL: C:/Server/Apache2.2/htdocs/www/public/index.php [IGNORING REWRITE]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]`

I don't understand. The second line will never match because of the first one ?

Comment: o.0 will try it and will post :P. So you are suggesting to remove the first one, or the second?

Comment: Why do you use `.htaccess`style files? It is much more complicated and expensice this way. Since you appear to have access to the servers configuration you certainly should put those rewriting rules into the main configuration area.

Comment: @php_nub_qq: no, the first rule catches only if the conditions are met. So some kind of exception rule.

Comment: @arkascha I prefer .htaccess style, cuz I hate to mess with configuration files (usually end up screwing something, when i can't get the desired effect)

Comment: As said: much more load for the server, and certainly much harder to debug. It has to parse and interpret the files _for each request_, compared to only once at server start when in the main configuration. Put things into a `conf.d` folder holding small rulesets included where required. That way you can also easily deactivate and exchange the rules.

Comment: Could agree with you.. But please focus on my problem, thanks for the tips I will keep them in mind :)

Comment: Your second rule will also only match if the conditions are met and in this case it wont match at all because of the first one and [L] in particular

Comment: @php_nub_qq: why that? The conditions always only count for a single following rule. All further rules are considered again without those conditions.

Comment: Try to make tripple sure that _both_ requests, the original one _and_ the rewritten one hit the virtual host.

Comment: I believe they apply to all rules. You can test it out anyway, just start removing stuff until you get it right?

Comment: Just played around with them if I remove either one of them I get the apache 404 page, I try http://mvc.local/etc/etc , but http://mvc.local/index.php/etc/etc all works well (Except that the framework does not expect idnex.php in the uri :D)

Comment: @php_nub_qq: fine if you believe that, but you are wrong. This is not a guessing game.

Comment: When having problems with rewriting rules, it _always_ is the first step to enable rewrite logging. Without it you stand in the dark, no sense in feeling your way. Open your eyes instead by looking at the rewrite log. Check the excellent documentation: `RewriteLog` and `RewriteLogLevel` are the commands you are looking for.

Comment: Yep added the results of 1 request with log level 4 :)

Comment: SOrry have added a request to without URI ie: http://mvc.local/ instead tested with: http://mvc.local/x -> which is existing page and it shows the content and shows the 404 in the Networking tab :)